# Live Video Broadcasting and Streaming in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, live-video

I want to develop an Android application that has functionality of video broadcasting and streaming from any mobile devices. I have already searched for many apis that might provide support for Android app development, but most of them have sdk's having support for Android 4.3+.

I have already looked for:

1) [StreamBox](http://www.streambox.com)

2) [ustream](http://www.ustream.tv)

3) [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com)

4) [KickFlip](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk)

5) [Aftek](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml)

Most of them just gave support for just web side or had support for version above 4.3+. I want any help in form of tutorials or documents that can help me live video stream and give some api support for my Android app development cycle. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did anyone get any material that might come in handy for me !!

Comment: You should use agora for live video streaming for Android, iOS, and flutter. The following link for a sample project in android using Agora.io I hope this will help.
[link](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Broadcasting/tree/master/OpenLive-Android)

Answer (score 0):

check this example application: http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/.